# Hiding columns based on cell value using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to hide columns based on a cell value.  This code works perfectly to hide rows but when I try and manipulate it to hide columns, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
Sub HideColumns()

    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For I = 1 To WS_Count

        For Each cell In Sheets(I).Range("P33:Y33")
            With cell
                .EntireColumn.Hidden = .Value = "HIDE"
            End With
        Next
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks perfectly correct. How doesnt it work? What error is it displaying?

Comment: @Lankymart it means hide the column if the cell's value is ""HIDE". If that's what the code is meant to do, then it works fine and it is perfectly correct. I dont have my Crystal ball to know what is the intent of the OP, that's why I ask. But the code is VB-correct, there is no syntax error in it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your line to `.EntireColumn.Hidden = True`.

You don't need to say the Value is hidden, simply the `EntireColumn`.

Comment: .Value = True evaluates to True.  if you remove that logic, then you are no longer checking the value of the cell!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfect here for me. All is correct. Maybe ist an idea to change the logic to

```
With cell
    If .Value = "HIDE" Then
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
End With
```

This is better to debug and understand why it works or not. Generally it is difficult to find a bug without the real data. Seems your bug is inside your data. Please check this carefully or post your data here.